# Chrome --kiosk-printing has 1-2 minute lag/delay

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, kiosk-mode

I need print receipt in Chrome running in

```
--kiosk
```

mode. Of course I use

```
--kiosk-printing
```

to disable print dialog. I have to note this parameter only emulate automatic pressing Print button.

My printer is Rongta RP80 80mm Thermal Receipt Printer connected via USB to laptop with Windows 10, Chrome 57.

Printing mechanism is easy, printing launches by javascript on page.

When I don't use --kiosk-printing parameter printing starts immediately on Print button press in chrome print preview dialog.

I face to *big* problem with --kiosk-printing: **printing starts only after 1-2 minutes since chrome printing dialog appear and disappear** (as noticed, parameter only emulate automatic pressing Print button). It is not printer problem, cause new document appear in windows print queue after this lag.

Why there is a so big lag with --kiosk-printing parameter, how to minimize it?

Comment: I checked Chromium browser on which Chrome based on - it has this bug too. So the source of --kiosk-printing has 1-2 minute lag/delay is Chromium.

Comment: Bug in chromium discussion: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706180
Solution at this time: use version 56 (http://www.geocities.jp/ecvcn/exam/chrome_installer.html)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem here when I upgrade chrome to version 57 recently. The only solution at the moment is install an older version of chrome. http://www.geocities.jp/ecvcn/exam/chrome_installer.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using Chrome Canary on a Windows 8.1 PC solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

mee too, but normal is quite slow, sometimes it not print anything... not only on --kiosk --kiosk-printing. after using Vivaldi (fork of

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in April, same in canary, users report that it's fixed in 58 (stable), just update chrome (in help menu, about Google chrome) :
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706180

So the bug is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Chrome browser property:

```
-kiosk --disable-print-preview
```

This will remove your pain.

Comment: This stops the --kiosk-printing from working